# How to create temp col ? mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

How to run this query correctly :

```
SELECT 
sum(1+1) as sum1,
sum(sum1 + 2) as sum2
```

I want to create variable sum1 and use it in other function !

Comment: `select 2, 4` ?  Can you better describe what you want to do?

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually my query is more complicated that this ! I will edit the answer, just give one minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery to alias expressions:

```
select  sum1
,       sum(sum1 + 2) as sum2
from    (
        select  sum(1+1) as sum1
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```